# Why won't RMarkdown with Bookdown recognize Tufte formatting?

Tags: r-markdown, tufte

I am working on a Bookdown project and would like to use Tufte formatting.

I downloaded the [Bookdown demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) and the **tufte** package. Then, I simply changed the YAML in `index.Rmd` to:

```r
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: 
    bookdown::tufte_html_book:
        toc: yes
        css: toc.css
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
---
```

Where the only change is in the `output:` option, which is specified by [the Bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#tufte-style)

And then tried both the Knit button and `bookdown::render_book()`. The demo built successfully.

However, it did not produce Tufte formatting. Instead I get default formatting, with a white background, non-italic section headings, and footnotes instead of margin notes (I added a footnote to the doc on a second run to make this visible):

[image: Bookdown built purportedly with Tufte]

I also tried this with different spacing before the "bookdown"/"toc" etc. stuff, and with `tufte::tufte_html: default` instead of any of the "bookdown"/"toc" stuff.

What do I need to do to get Bookdown to recognize the Tufte formatting request? I feel like I am missing something exceedingly simple.

Comment: According [to this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/tufte-handouts.html) you use `tufte::tufte_book` As output format for HTML tufte book

Comment: `tufte::tufte_book` is for PDF output, not HTML. Regardless, I similarly get the default non-Tufte formatting when I use it, as well.